# Call non-virtual protected methods from a Java/C# subclass in Clojure/ClojureCLR

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

When making a subclass in Clojure using gen-class, you can expose protected virtual(non-final) methods through exposes-methods, however it is implemented through overriding, which cannot work for non-virtual(final) methods.

Is the only way to call a protected method this way through reflection?

Can reify or proxy do this better than gen-class?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-vritual methods" here? Static? Final?

Comment: In c# the term is virtual. In java I believe methods are virtual by default, but final means non-virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in clojure-clr. It probably works fine in the JVM version. Clojure does allow calling non-virtual/final methods if they're protected/public. However, the method I was trying to call was protected internal, which actually means protected *or* internal. clojure-clr was incorrectly interpreting this as protected *and* internal, internal meaning only accessible within the same assembly. Due to this, my method call was failing.

This has been fixed in the latest version of clojure-clr.